# MySQL database design to store geospatial data with internationalization and history support

Tags: mysql, internationalization, historical-db

I'm working on a a database schema to store geospatial datas, I need to support internationalization of the strings like point's name and description, and to support the logging of all the modifications.

This is my current schema :

```
points
---------------
rev_id (int autoincrement)
rev_from (date)
rev_to (date)
rev_operation (insert/update/delete)
rev_user (user who has made the modification)
point_id (int)
point_geom (geometry)
point_name_en
point_desc_en
point_name_fr
point_desc_fr
```

It works fine, but I must update the design each time I add a new language, and, in the case I update one translation I must copy an entire row... this leads to data duplication. So to avoid that I want to put the localized strings in another table :

```
points
---------------
rev_id (int autoincrement)
rev_from (date)
rev_to (date)
rev_operation (insert/update/delete)
rev_user (user who has made the modification)
point_id (int)
point_geom (geometry)

points_text
---------------
point_id (int)
lang_code (en/fr/es/it etc...)
point_name
point_desc
```

It works, but I can't track the modifications of translations.

What's the best way to design a database which store objects with their properties's translations and the history of the properties' modifications.

Comment: Why can't you track modification in the 2nd example?

Comment: Because I must add revisions fields in the 'points_text' database, it would be complicated and I don't know how to retrieve the state of a particular revision in this case. Ex : I change the english translation of a point's name, I add a row in the 'points_text' table, but there's no correlation between the revisions in 'points' table and the 'points_text' table. Mmmm perhaps I need to put another table to do that.

Comment: i think you have a mistake in points_text?  it should have point_name and point_desc (they will be in the language that corresponds to lang_code).

Comment: yep sorry I'm updating this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not add rev_ fields to points_text (which i think has errors - see my comments on the question)?

you need to separate the two concepts: inserting points and inserting texts.  both can have revisions.  sometime both may occur together.

if you want you could then move that revision data out into a separate table and reference it from both the points tables.  that would let you share the same entry when both are modified together.

Comment: I'd like to avoid this, because in the real application usage, if I want to display an history of modifications (as MediaWiki), I will have to display an historical tree for the points and another for the strings. I don't know if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: in that case it sounds like a higher level problem - you need to think through what "a change" is and how it is made by a user, how it fits with other definitions in other languages, and how you will show it.  at the moment you don't have a clear idea (as far as i can tell).  it seems more conceptual than a database problem...

Comment: the points and theirs attributes come from an OpenLayers application which communicate a Restfull API, and this is the scheme of the database I'd like to build. The points consist of a couple of geometry coordinates and various attributes like name, description, type etc... and these attributes need to be translated. In usual operations it's true the users can edit only the point coordinate or the text fields or both. I think I will try your suggestion. Many thanks ;)